# Generalize <random> generators

Tags: c++, performance, templates, random, generator

There are several different types of random number generators defined in `<random>` like `minstd_rand0` or `mt19937`, but they don't share a common base even though they have the exact same member functions (like `operator()` or `min` and `max`). Thus, to use such a generator with a distribution like `uniform_int_distribution` the distribution's function also has to be a template. And if I wanted to store a generator in a different class I would have to make that class a template class with the generator as template parameter like this:

```
template <typename generator_t>
class foo
{
    generator_t gen;
}
```

A way to generalize the use of those generators would be to abstract them into a function object of type `std::function<int()>` and then write a method which returns such a function object generator given an ordinary generator from `<random>` like so (optionally with a distribution included):

```
template <typename generator_t>
std::function<int()> create_generator(generator_t& gen)
    return [gen](){
        return gen();
    };
}
```

Similarly one could also create a class that abstracts all other functions available in the ordinary generators. In both cases it would unnecessarily lower the performance because of these indirections.

Since I generate a huge amount of random numbers I need the process to be as efficient as possible while also enabling me to swap out generators or distributions without having to rewrite any code. I don't like the option of making all the classes that use random number generation template classes with the generator type as template parameter just because the generators defined in `<random>` don't have a common base. Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: Using templates is actually the most efficient solution (and it seems like you care about efficiency). If you were going to use virtual function based polymorphism (if it were possible), it would be less efficient.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that too. If I were actually to use template parameters for the generator and all distributions though I would already have 5 different template parameters in some algorithm that uses 4 different distributions for random numbers. That makes the code ugly and unreadable.

Comment: I imagine most of those template parameters can be deduced. If it's for a class, you can imitate `make_pair` and use `auto` to avoid repeating yourself.

Comment: You can also make no-overhead wrapper classes that obscure template parameters that aren't relevant to your code.  It's starting to seem like your real question is "How do I make these template-heavy objects more readable?"

Comment: " it would unnecessarily lower the performance because of these indirections". Virtual functions also are indirect. You simply can't have both, type erasure and direct calls. You can't call `Derived::Foo` directly if you don't know about `Derived`.

Comment: "How do I make these template-heavy objects more readable?" Maybe so, but making it "prettier" isn't going to change much. Generally it's possible to have an indirection which obscures which generator is used using std::function, so I assumed there were other ways to do the same thing. Apparently the overhead of std::function is really bad when the function iself isn't doing much. Virtual functions and polymorphism would (probably?) have less impact on the performance. And if I could solve this problem with polymorphism with an acceptable performance, that's what Id prefer.

Comment: Hmm...maybe someone should write a library abstracting different RNGs...